# How can I update length of array in parent component from changing value in child component in Angular4?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-components

I am working on e-commerce site in Angular4.I need to show a number of items present in a cart in nav bar which is written in app.component and in my product details page add to cart option is present.When a user clicks on add to cart button, a number of items showing in a cart in navbar have to be incremented.How can I implement this in Angular4?Below is my code:

```js
app.component.ts:
    if(this.storage.retrieve('cartList')==undefined){
    this.storage.store('cartList',this.cartData)

    }
    else{      
        this.cartData=this.storage.retrieve('cartList');
    }
if(this.cartData){
       this.length=this.cartData.length;
    }
else{
   this.length=0; 
}
productdetails.ts:
addToCart(data){
        this.addCart=true;
        this.addedOne=false;
        this.hideCart=true;
        this.continueShopping=false;
   this.cartItems.push(data)
   this.storage.store("cartList",this.cartItems);
   console.log(this.cartItems.length)
}
```

```html
/*app.component.html:*/
 <a (click)="goToCart()" style="cursor:pointer">
                                    <h3>
                                        <div class="total">
                        
                                            (<span>{{this.length}}</span> items)</div>
                                        <img src="assets/images/bag.png" alt="" />
                                    </h3>
                                </a>
```

Comment: you need to look at [even emitters](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/event) if thay have a parent child relation ship

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your child and parent you do a couple of things.

In your child component:

```
@Output() updateCart: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>(); // before constructor

addToCart(data){
  //fill carts
  this.storage.store("cartList",this.cartItems);
  this.updateCart.emit(true); // trigger parent
```

In the parent html:

```
<child (updateCart)="updateCart($event)"></child>
```

And in the parent component: **EDIT**

```
private updateCart(_boolean: any){
  this.cartData = this.storage.retrieve('cartList');
  this.length = this.cartData.length;
}
```

Comment: where can I display the length in parent html?

Comment: @srujana Same place. Check my edit .
Ohh btw it's `{{length}}` not `{{this.length}}`

Comment: In general is a "bad idea" have "duplicate" items. You have: this.storage, this.cartData and lenght. Why not use {{CartData.length}} or, better, Why not use only this.storage?

Comment: It's his implementation not mine I only give a solution for his question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@Output()` and `EventEmitter` for communication between child and parent component.

`Child Component`

```
import {Output,EventEmitter} from '@angular/core'
export class child{
   @Output() cartLength : EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
}
```

emit the length whenever the products increase by `this.cartLength.emit(productLength);`

To Listen to the event,

in your parent Template,

`<child (cartLength)=cartLengthChanged($event)><child>`

Define the `cartLengthChanged()` in parent `.ts` file :

`cartLengthChanged(event){
 console.log(event);//event will be data to be passed from child to parent
}`